# Seam 3 exception handler - redirection doesn't work

Tags: jsf, exception, seam, seam3

What can be cause of not working redirection in this case?

```
@HandlesExceptions
public class ExceptionHandler {
    public void handleException(@Handles CaughtException<Throwable> e,
                                Messages messages      
                                FacesContext facesContext){

        messages.error("something went wrong");
        facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler()    
                .handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "foopage");
    }
}
```

I'm sure that exception handler method is processed. How can I redirect to some error page in exception handler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after calling "handleNavigation", you should call :
facescontext.renderResponse();